# Return array item by index in a meteor spacebars template

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I want to access the first item of an array inside a meteor template, I'm using this syntax :

```
<p>{{array[0]}}</p>
```

However it doesn't seem like it's working. I don't want to iterate through values using `{{#each}}`, just pick the first one from the array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is just a problem of syntax, the correct one is the following :

```
<p>{{array.[0]}}</p>
```

Notice the `.` dot between the array property and the brackets (array indexing) notation ?

Here is the (hidden) docs for this :

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#dotted-helpers-with-numeric-indices

Comment: it doesn't work anymore I just try with an array of object from database and I got [object Object]

Comment: @saimeunt: Do you know how to do this for a runtime index? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815019/return-array-item-by-index-variable-in-a-meteor-spacebars-template