# Return array item by index/variable in a meteor spacebars template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

How can I access the X item of an array inside a meteor template?

Thanks to [Return array item by index in a meteor spacebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843646/return-array-item-by-index-in-a-meteor-spacebars-template) I know how to do that for a specific index:

```
<p>{{array.[0]}}</p>
```

But my question is how to do that for a runtime defined index.
Let say that X is defined and with a valid value. Why is this not working for me?

```
<p>{{array.[X]}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

`<p>{{array.[index]}}</p>`
eg.
`<p>{{array.[0]}}</p>`

or

```
{{#each getArray}}
    <div class="item" data-value="{{someHelper @index}}">
        {{this}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: First option did not work for me.
Second one works, but I'll prefer to avoid using a helper.
Any other idea?

Comment: @rafahoro> I don't understand your problem with a helper? security, performance, re-usability, ...?

Comment: @JeanRAKOTO just to make code easy to follow (for me at least).  The need to go to a helper, just to access an array, seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here,

I end using a general helpers, 
`{{arrayIndex array index}}`

As simple as

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating'

Template.registerHelper('arrayIndex', function (array, index) {
  return array[index]
})
```